# Creating Bottom Navigation Bar for Android and iOS using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is it possible to create bottom navigation bar for Android and iOS using Xamarin Forms without using Custom renderer.

I heard that the latest Xamarin Forms support bottom Navigation bar feature, but sadly I was not able to find the appropriate documentation.

Need some help / guidelines to implement the same.

Comment: Check if this helps: https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-official-bottom-navigation-bottom-tabs-on-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sharing My Application code, hope it will help you.

XML Page :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="iSAS.Mobile.Views.Student.SettingsPage"
         Title="Profile" 
         xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
         BarBackgroundColor="White"
         BarTextColor="#2196F3" 
         android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
         android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#66FFFFFF"
         android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="#2196F3" >
 </TabbedPage>
```

CS Page :

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class SettingsPage : TabbedPage
{
    public SettingsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Children.Add(new ProfilePage());
        Children.Add(new ChangePassword());
        Children[0].Icon = "profile.png";
        Children[1].Icon = "settings.png";

        CurrentPage = Children[1];
    }

    public SettingsPage(bool DefaultChangePswdPage = true)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Children.Add(new ProfilePage());
        Children.Add(new ChangePassword());
        Children[0].Icon = "profile.png";

        Children[1].Icon = "settings.png";
        if (DefaultChangePswdPage)
            CurrentPage = Children[1];
    }
}
```